# In R, how can I vectorize a moving subset of data?

Tags: r

I have a loop below that assigns two new columns to a data table, using the last 21 days of data with 10 samples per day. It works but is very inefficient and I would like help on how to vectorize a moving subset. I have a feeling an "apply" function is involved, but I'm not sure how to work with a subset that is not constant. Below is my loop- I start by assigning zeros to the new columns because I think modifying values in-place is faster than adding new values every iteration.

```
data$up <- 0
data$down <- 0

for (i in ((21*10)+1): nrow(data)) {
  sub <- subset(data, data$date[i-(21*10)] < data$date &  data$date < data$date[i])
  data$up[i] <- mean(sub$ratio) + 2.25*sd(sub$ratio)
  data$down[i] <- mean(sub$ratio) - 2.25*sd(sub$ratio)
}
```

And [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hmhlg.png) is sample data and my expected output. Thank you for the help!

Comment: Is there only 10 data point per day?

Comment: Yes, only 10 data points per day

Comment: Please dont post images instead use `dput` to show the data

Comment: Hey @akrun, I used dput() on my trimmed down data table and I have a long list of values now. What's the best way to show this data? Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***EDITED** for the desired result I didn't see initially.

Basically, I'm using dplyr to create a rolling mean and sd columns using `RcppRoll`. Then, `group by` date and mutate again to keep only the last entry per day. We have to do this to make sure the sd is calculated correctly.

```
library(RcppRoll); library(dplyr)
data <- data.frame(date=rep(seq.Date(from=as.Date("2017-01-01"),to=as.Date("2017-05-01"),by="days"),each =10),
                   ratio=1:110,stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
data%>%
  mutate(up=roll_meanr(ratio,n=21*10)+2.25*roll_sdr(ratio,n=21*10),
         down=roll_meanr(ratio,n=21*10)-2.25*roll_sdr(ratio,n=21*10))%>%
  group_by(date)%>%
  mutate(up=last(up),down=last(down))

         date ratio       up      down
       <date> <int>    <dbl>     <dbl>
1  2017-04-30    96 121.9414 -15.70329
2  2017-04-30    97 121.9414 -15.70329
3  2017-04-30    98 121.9414 -15.70329
4  2017-04-30    99 121.9414 -15.70329
5  2017-04-30   100 121.9414 -15.70329
6  2017-05-01   101 126.7033 -10.94139
7  2017-05-01   102 126.7033 -10.94139
8  2017-05-01   103 126.7033 -10.94139
9  2017-05-01   104 126.7033 -10.94139
10 2017-05-01   105 126.7033 -10.94139
11 2017-05-01   106 126.7033 -10.94139
12 2017-05-01   107 126.7033 -10.94139
13 2017-05-01   108 126.7033 -10.94139
14 2017-05-01   109 126.7033 -10.94139
15 2017-05-01   110 126.7033 -10.94139
```

**EDIT2** If you're ok with the standard deviation to be calculated on the mean per day (instead of all 210 values), you can do this:

```
data%>%
  group_by(date)%>%
  summarise(mean_ratio=mean(ratio))%>%
  mutate(up=roll_meanr(mean_ratio,n=21)+2.25*roll_sdr(mean_ratio,n=21),
         down=roll_meanr(mean_ratio,n=21)-2.25*roll_sdr(mean_ratio,n=21))%>%
  left_join(data,.)

           date ratio mean_ratio       up      down
1196 2017-04-30    96       95.5 123.1605 -16.92239
1197 2017-04-30    97       95.5 123.1605 -16.92239
1198 2017-04-30    98       95.5 123.1605 -16.92239
1199 2017-04-30    99       95.5 123.1605 -16.92239
1200 2017-04-30   100       95.5 123.1605 -16.92239
1201 2017-05-01   101      105.5 127.9224 -12.16049
1202 2017-05-01   102      105.5 127.9224 -12.16049
1203 2017-05-01   103      105.5 127.9224 -12.16049
1204 2017-05-01   104      105.5 127.9224 -12.16049
1205 2017-05-01   105      105.5 127.9224 -12.16049
1206 2017-05-01   106      105.5 127.9224 -12.16049
1207 2017-05-01   107      105.5 127.9224 -12.16049
1208 2017-05-01   108      105.5 127.9224 -12.16049
1209 2017-05-01   109      105.5 127.9224 -12.16049
1210 2017-05-01   110      105.5 127.9224 -12.16049
```

Comment: Thank you very much @P Lapointe! Is there any way to roll values such that I have the same value for every day? If I include parameter by=90, that doesn't give me the desired result

Comment: @Anna Like I said, because sd is calculated using the mean of all observations, you can't group by day. This is why I'm using `mutate(up=last(up),down=last(down))` to change data to the last data point. I'll add another solution, which is the sd of daily means (21 data points instead of 210)

Comment: Thank you @P Lapointe- I'm still a little confused by your use of %>%. I typed out what you wrote from "data%>%" onward and I get the error "could not find function "%>%", even after installing the magrittr package

Comment: @Anna You need to install these two packages: `library(RcppRoll); library(dplyr)` "%>%" is a function of magrittr, which is a dependency of dplyr and will be installed by dplyr.  "%>%" is called a piping operator. The result of one line is "piped" to the next.

Comment: @P Lapointe I'm super appreciative of your help, and sorry for all the follow up questions! When I run your code above in edit 1, I see the same dataframe in my console, but the dataframe in my environment only contains the date and ratio columns. Shouldn't mutate modify my object directly?

Comment: @Anna With pipes (%>%), you have to assign the pipeline to an object. The first line should look like this: `data <- data%>%` This will overwrite the data object with the calculated result. Youd could also put the results in a new object: `data2 <- data%>%`